# Cannot log into freshy installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.3: login incorrect?

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, virtualbox, login, password

I installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 (kernel version 4.4.0.87) in a VirtualBox Virtual Machine. No fancy settings, pretty much just a straightforward default install.

After the installation was finished and I booted the first time, I was unable to login ("login incorrect").

After some attempts in disbelief, I assumed I must have made a typing mistake during the installation, so I just installed the whole thing again. Same problem. I was now convinced something was fishy, so I reinstalled it *again*, took extra care and triple-checked every step, making 100% absolutely certain I am entering the right username and password everywhere.

During this last installation I made screenshots of the installation process. Click on each image for the full resolution version:

1. Specifying the username:

   [image: username]
   <sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>
2. Specifying the password:

   [image: password]
3. Confirming password:

   [image: confirm password]
4. After installation was finished, booting my freshly installed Ubuntu:

   [image: login]

I am absolutely 100% sure I am entering the exact right details. No dumb mistakes like keeping caps lock on or mistakenly using a Dvorak keyboard or anything.

What am I doing wrong?

(edit) I also tried the 'recover lost password' procedure. Note that this doesn't really apply here, **I didn't lose my password, I'm 100% sure, see screenshots from installation**. Nonetheless I tried this anyway, going in rescue mode and root prompt, and when I do: `passwd kenneth` 
To my surprise I get: `passwd: user 'kenneth' does not exist`

Again, note that I'm 100% sure that I specified my username `kenneth` during the installation.

Then I did: `more /etc/shadow` and I get a list of typical system user accounts, like root, daemon, bin, sys, and so on. **But no 'kenneth' account** nor any other that looks like a user account, only the typical system accounts. In fact there are none with an actual password, they all have `!` or `*` for the password hash.

I also did `ls -al /home`, nothing there.

**What could be the reason for an Ubuntu installer to not create the user account as specified during the installation?**

Note that I didn't get any errors during the entire installation, everything worked smoothly and straightforward from beginning till end.

Comment: Reset it from the rescue mode!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: @George Thanks, tried that, but to no avail. See also the added section to my post.

Comment: May be a reinstall would be in order if this is fresh install

Comment: @George I have already attempted to reinstall several times. This problem keeps coming back (see also post, my description and screenshots were already from the *third* time I reinstalled it).

Comment: Same problem with Ubuntu 18.04. It sucks.

Comment: Same with 18.10

Comment: Ist there any folder in `/home`? during installation, if you check the output of the installer, do you see any error when the `adduser` is called?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a bug, but you can avoid it. Add user in rescue mode. Make uid of that user = 1000. Check /etc/shadow to be sure all done well. Reboot and have fun.

`# adduser --uid 1000 username`

If uid 1000 is used already, then just add user with uid above 1000